# What's the difference between using DatabaseConfig and Database in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I was reading about `DatabaseConfig` in [slick's documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/database.html#databaseconfig):

> On top of the configuration syntax for `Database`, there is another
>   layer in the form of `DatabaseConfig` which allows you to configure a
>   Slick driver plus a matching `Database` together. **This makes it easy to
>   abstract over different kinds of database systems by simply changing a
>   configuration file**.

I don't get this part, how `DatabaseConfig` makes the underlying database system more abstract than the `Database` approach? Suppose, i'm using `DatabaseConfig` in the following test:

```
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FlatSpec}
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class DatabaseConfigTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  def withDb(test: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] => Any) = {
    val dbConfig = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("abstract")

    try test(dbConfig)
    finally dbConfig.db.close()
  }

  "DatabaseConfig" should "work" in withDb { dbConfig =>
    import Supplier._

    val cities = suppliers.map(_.city)

    dbConfig.db.run(cities.result).map(_.foreach(println))
  }
}
```

As you can see, if i change my underlying database system from `PostgreSQL` to `MySQL`, in addition to configuration change, i need to change the `import` statement that imports the postgre API to mysql's. On the other hand, If i was using `Database`:

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class DatabaseTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  def withDb(test: Database => Any) = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("default")

    try test(db)
    finally db.close()
  }

  "Supplier names" should "be fetched" in withDb { db =>
    import Supplier._

    val names = suppliers.map(_.name)

    db.run(names.result).map(_.foreach(println))
  }
}
```

When i'm using `Database`, same change on the underlying database, would result in two changes: one in configuration file and the other in source code. With all these being said, how one approach is more abstract than the other one? Am i using `DatabaseConfig` wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but you aren't quite using `DatabaseConfig` properly. Rather than importing a specific driver, you need to import the driver associated with the config. Something like this should work:

```
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FlatSpec}
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
//import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class DatabaseConfigTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  def withDb(test: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] => Any) = {
    val dbConfig = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("abstract")

    /* The api for the driver specified in the config is imported here. */
    import dbConfig.driver.api._  

    try test(dbConfig)
    finally dbConfig.db.close()
  }

  "DatabaseConfig" should "work" in withDb { dbConfig =>
    import Supplier._

    val cities = suppliers.map(_.city)

    dbConfig.db.run(cities.result).map(_.foreach(println))
  }
}
```

This should allow you to switch databases in the config without having to change any code or recompile.

Comment: thanks..but how can i use `dbConfig.driver.api._ ` in my entity definitions e.g. `Supplier`? I still have some database specific `import` in those classes.

Comment: There are a couple of different ways that you could handle this. You could create an object to hold the config object that is accessible to the entity definition. Then within the schema entity you could `import DbConfigHolderObject.dbConfig.driver.api._`. You could also create a trait that does the setup and mix it into the schema entities.

Comment: Just thought of this... I think the best way to handle it would probably be to use an implicit.

Comment: Thanks DemetriKots..that was a great idea