# Import different db drivers in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Slick 3 has "import api" to use specific database driver. e.g.

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
...DAO implementation...
```

or

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
...DAO implementation...
```

How do I use postgresql in production and h2 in unit test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DatabaseConfig`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/api/index.html#slick.backend.DatabaseConfig) instead. As [Slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/database.html#databaseconfig) states:

> On top of the configuration syntax for `Database`, there is another
>   layer in the form of `DatabaseConfig` which allows you to configure a
>   Slick driver plus a matching Database together. This makes it easy to
>   abstract over different kinds of database systems by **simply changing a
>   configuration file.**

Instead of importing database specific drivers, first obtain a `DatabaseConfig`:

```
val dbConfig = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("<db_name>")
```

And then import api from it:

```
import dbConfig.driver.api._
```

Comment: Is it possible to use with custom driver class? e.g. https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg I tried but it seem that it does not recognise some custom implicits

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636436/whats-the-difference-between-using-databaseconfig-and-database-in-slick